# select distinct values and order by the same column(value)

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, distinct

I have tried to find something to help me with this, but no luck.

I have a column "slide_no" with values 1-4.
I want to select everything from the database with distinct slide_no order by slide_no but show random selected images.

Database table

```
slide_id | slide_name  | slide_no | fk_project_id
  1      | pic1.jpg    |   1      |  2
  2      | pic2.jpg    |   3      |  4
  3      | pic3.jpg    |   2      |  3
  4      | pic4.jpg    |   4      |  1
  5      | pic5.jpg    |   2      |  6
  6      | pic6.jpg    |   3      |  5
```

As you can see, the slide_no don't have to be unique, and I want it to be able to show random images on each page load. So far, I have only been able to produce a query that get the first 4 images out.

Is it possible to order by slide_no and get random images, with different (still ordered by slide_no) images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "random slide images"

Comment: I believe op wants a random image from the images where slide_no = 1, a random image from the images where slide_no = 2, a random image from the images where slide_no = 3, and a random image from the images where slide_no = 4.

Comment: Yes, a random image from the images where slide_no = 1 and so on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0664c/8

```
Select slide_name, slide_no From
(SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY slide_no, slide_name 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) `tempTable`
 ) x
Group by slide_no
ORDER BY slide_no ASC
limit 4
```

Comment: This almost made my day! The pictures did change, but unfortunately it remains the same pictures.
Would it be possible to change this so it selects a random image but orders by 'slide_n'?

Comment: It looked like it was working for a minute, but it selects all images and put them all out. Even though only 4 of them is showing, you can see all 6 in the source code. I tried a LIMIT 4 but then it selects 4 random again, and it can have 1,2,2,3 (example) - missing slide_no = 4 and having and extra slide_no = 2. Tried a distinct before slide_no but that caused an error.

Comment: Working, only problem is, it only select the 4 first images in the database, also in the live test :)

Comment: Wow! How would a newbie like me ever figure that out? ^^ It's working like a charm! Thanks Evan! :)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL provides [`ORDER BY RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) for this.

> `ORDER BY RAND()` combined with `LIMIT` is useful for selecting a random sample from a set of rows.

The query will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *
    FROM `tblName`
    GROUP BY slide_no 
    ORDER BY RAND()
) `tempTable`
ORDER BY slide_no ASC
```

Comment: I have tried the ORDER BY RAND() but it mixed up the order of it. What I need is a random picture ordered by slide_no (asc).

Comment: I may seem ignorant now, but what is the `tempTable`?

Comment: @Niantic Just an alias given to the table generated inside the braces.

Comment: So from what I understand, I can let it stay as TempTable, right? Sorry, you never learn if you don't ask :)

Comment: Made one that works, except it can select 2 of the same slide_no
Can I use the distinct to fix that, you think?

Comment: You can use either of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. Your choice @Niantic

Comment: The `GROUP BY` makes it static and I can't figure where to put the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: SELECT *
          FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM `topslides` WHERE slide_no IN (1, 2, 3, 4)           
           ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
          ) `tempTable`
          ORDER BY slide_no ASC

Comment: Put the `GROUP BY slide_no` just before `ORDER BY slide_no ASC`.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference to the result. It does select what I want it to, but it has multiple slide_no. fx: It has: slide_no = 1, slide_no = 2, slide_no = 2, slide_no = 4

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this if your just looking for a single random ID each time.

```
SELECT slide_id
FROM {table_name} 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT slide_no
, ( SELECT TOP 1 slide_name 
    FROM #tmp T2 
    WHERE T2.slide_no = T1.slide_no     
    ORDER BY RAND() --You can place other logic to "randomize" here in the future
   )
FROM #tmp T1
GROUP BY slide_no;
```

I'm not sure if this gives you what you're looking for.  The problem is that the repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.  If you want it to be truly random, that's another question in itself.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) for generating a random number in SQL.

Comment: Pretty sure that the question had MySQL tag.